# Cannot pull images using authenticated user in GitlabCI

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker

I'm trying to mitigate the DockerHub pull limit by logging in to a DockerHub account in my `gitlab-runner`. I'm not using methods like Gitlab's Dependency proxy because I would have to edit hundreds of files. I decided to log in to Docker in `gitlab-runner`.

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: docker

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - base

docker-build:
  stage: base
  tags:
    - experimental
  script:
    - docker build -t grex:alpine_${CI_PIPELINE_ID} ./alpine
    - docker info
```

The `alpine` folder contains a Dockerfile containing just `FROM alpine`.
The `config.toml` of the `gitlab-runner` has the line `pre_build_script = "docker login -u grex -p <password>"`

The `docker info` line states that my user is logged in.
I followed all of the options from [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#authenticate-with-registry-in-docker-in-docker) but to no avail. After each pipeline run, I checked the current rate limit for my user and it remained unchanged, leaving me to infer the pipeline made an unauthenticated docker pull. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation, it seems Gitlab caches images and that resulted in the number of pulled images to not change.